# Passing parent as child reference as an argument to a function that accepts the children as argument in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, overloading

Maybe the title is uncorrect, so I'll explain more precisely what I need to do.
I have rewritten an "`Observer-Observable" interface` to let my `Observer` do an **overloading** of the method `update(Observable o, Object arg)` based on various notified `Events` that I wrote (I'm not using the ones in `java.awt`).
For example

```
public interface RewrittenObserver{
    public void update(RewrittenObservable o, EventChild1 event);
    public void update(RewrittenObservable o, EventChild2 event);
    public void update(RewrittenObservable o, EventChild3 event);
    .....
}
```

Every function in my program returns a EventChild (with Event as abstract class father).

```
public Event returnMeAnEvent(){... return new EventChild1()};
```

and the RewrittenObservable notifies it calling the update of the Observer.

```
public abstract class RewrittenObservable {
     private RewrittenObserver observer;
     /*....Constructor definitions...*/
     public void notify(EventChild1 event){
         observer.update(this, event);
     }
}
```

I'm using an extension of the `RewrittenObservable` class

```
public class ObservableChild extends RewrittenObservable{
    ....
    public void doSomething(){... notifyChild(returnMeAnEvent())};
    public void notifyChild(EventChild1 event){
      super.notify(event);
}
```

The problem is that the `ObservableChild` class can't call the `super.notify(event)` because the **return** of the `returnMeAnEvent()` function is an abstract type (while I'm actually returning a child reference), so it actually searches for

```
public void notify(Event event){
}
```

Do I have a problem in *understanding inheritance*? What can you suggest me to get around the problem? I don't know if it's better to `@Override` the `notify` method in the `ObservableChild` class or using the `super.notify()` method and try to make it work.

Comment: Is `returnMeAnEvent()` returning a single type of event or different types? If single, you could add generics to make it compile-time safe, if not, you might have to dispatch the events by yourself, because there is no mechanism in Java to ensure a class to have a number of methods where there is one overload for every class in the class hierarchy.

Comment: Do you have any limitations to use a generic contract like `public <E extends Event> void notify(E event) {`

Comment: @Smutje it returns references of `EventChild1`, `EventChild2`, ecc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to change `RewrittenObservable` as follows:

```
public abstract class RewrittenObservable {
     // ...
     public void <T extends Event> notify(T event) {
         observer.update(this, event);
     }
}
```

Be aware that this may not work with the current Structure of `RewrittenObserver`, because the overloading is possibly ambiguous. You probably want a generic interface anyways and instead specialize the event handling in a proper implementation.

This also greatly simplifies implementing the `RewrittenObserver`

```
public interface RewrittenObserver<T extends Event> {
     public void update(RewrittenObservable o, T event);
}
```

and for specific child classes then use:

```
public class EventChild1Observer implements RewrittenObserver<EventChild1> {
    @Override
    public void update(RewrittenObservable o, EventChild1 event) {
        // implementation here
    }
}
```

On a sidenote: [this codereview-question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/84037/37660) and it's answers are probably of interest to you.

Comment: This would actually require to write a child class of Observer for every EventChild, correct? I've got many Event classes, why would overloading be a problem?

Comment: Not Quite correct. You can provide a "generic" implementation of `RewrittenObserver` that just takes `Event` instead of a child class. Also: what would be the problem to create a class? It's not even a little more effort than adding yet another overload to the long list... It's not that Overloading is a problem in and of itself. The use you make of it is. When you implement that interface, you'll have to override each and every single EventChild overload you have, even if you don't need them. Keep responsibilites separate ;)